# swap color channel for raw file (BGGR -> RGGB)

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors

I know there is a rawpy python library to open the raw file, but in order to modify the pixel data, the original data from raw need to be demosaiced. Could anyone provide a solution to swap the color channel for **raw** file encoded as BGGR? Thanks!

Edit1: I now have a python(2.7) script that can does the job but saves it as **tiff** format instead of **raw**.

```
import rawpy
import imageio

path = 'xxxx.raw'
raw = rawpy.imread(path)
rgb = raw.postprocess()
for x in rgb:
    for y in x:
        temp = y[0]
        y[0] = y[2]
        y[2] = temp
raw.raw_image
imageio.imsave('default.tiff', rgb)
```

Basically the question is how can I store the image back into **raw** format? Is the conversion from tiff to raw lossy?

Additionally, is there any way to not demosaic the raw file and swap the bytes(SBGGR8 to SRGGB8)? This way seems no data loss problem.

Edit2: Here is my raw metadata process MATLAB code that can swap the channel lossless. But MATLAB is not free software, I am looking for a python version. As I am not a python file process expert, could somebody help me with my script?

```
row = 640;  col = 480;
fin = fopen('original.raw','r');
input = fread(fin,row*col,'uint8=>uint8'); 
output = reshape(input,row,col);
for y = 1:2:639
    for x = 1:2:479
        temp = output(y,x);
        output(y,x) = output(y+1, x+1);
        output(y+1, x+1) = temp;
    end
end
fout = fopen('swapped.raw', 'w');
fwrite(fout,output);
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```

Comment: How about you try to do it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the lossless way of swapping the B and R channel by using Python 2.7.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import numpy as np
row = 480
col = 640
fin = open('example.raw','r')
inp = np.fromfile(fin,np.dtype(np.uint8),row*col)
output = np.reshape(inp,(row,col))

def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for y in my_range(0, row-2, 2):
    for x in my_range(0, col-2, 2):
        temp = output[y][x]
        output[y][x] = output[y+1][x+1]
        output[y+1][x+1] = temp

fout = open('output.raw','w')
fout.writelines(output)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```